# How can I get the type of a Type?

Tags: c#

Given the following method:

```
public dynamic ConvertIt(dynamic source, Type dest)
      {
         return Convert.ChangeType(source, dest);
      }
```

How can I get the actual primitive type of dest?

I would expect something like :

```
if (dest is bool)
```

However I get a design time warning that the type condition will never meet, which is obvious because dest is always Type.

I would expect to be able to get to an enum of types (primitives), a property of dest.

Comment: Why the downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator with your known type and compare that with the `dest` type:

```
if (dest == typeof(bool))
```

(Reference equality is fine here, as each type only has a single `Type` object representing it.)

It's not clear what you mean by "get to an enum of types (primitives), a property of dest" - but if you want to check whether `dest` is one of a bunch of types, you could create a `List<Type>` or `HashSet<Type>` and just use `acceptableTypes.Contains(dest)`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to get the type of `dest`,get the type of `bool` instead and compare:

```
if(dest == typeof(bool))
```

You are getting a warning because `Type` class it not compatible `bool`.Therefore the expression will always return `false`.